# Facebook Chat API and OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-opengraph, facebook-chat

If I send a private message to a friend, and that message includes a link, Facebook automatically appends the site's icon, description, etc. to the message (assuming that site supports open graph).

However, when I use the Chat API to send that link to a friend, it doesn't do that. It just sends the link, but doesn't use the open graph information of the site to display image, description, etc.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to do this in PHP, I would recommend you to extend [echo_facebook_client.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/echo_facebook_client.php) sample example which comes bundled with [Jaxl library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/). This will let you send private message to a friend using your facebook application oauth tokens.

Last time when I checked [facebook jabber documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) (which was a few months back), there was no official way to attach link metadata within a chat context. Under limitations section of the doc you will find:

```
Your client cannot send or receive HTML messages
```

Comment: Yea, I am afraid it's actually not possible. That sucks.